Opencv cornerSubPix not able to find a good corner
I am trying to find a corner for this image. The corner seems clear enough for me but for some reason the algorithm doesn't seem to get it right.
I have been playing with the knobs available (termination criteria, windows size, and zero zone (although not really sure what this means, the documentation doesn't say much)), I feel I am almost there but no quite. Any guidance will be appreciated.
cv::TermCriteria criteria = cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER  | cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 0.1);
cv::cornerSubPix(image_gray, corners, cv::Size(10, 10) /*windows size*/, cv::Size(-1,-1) /*zero zone*/, criteria);

UPDATE 1:
This is the original image and belongs to a Charuco board generated with the following parameters
rows = 19, cols 24, square_width = 0.05, marker_width=0.04, dictionary = 5x5_1000 with legacy_charuco flag enabled
cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_5X5_1000);
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::CharucoBoard> board = cv::makePtr<cv::aruco::CharucoBoard>(cv::Size(19, 34), 0.05f, 0.04f, dictionary);
board->setLegacyPattern(true);

The charuco/aruco detectors provided by OpenCV are unable to find the top-left intersection and some other corners at the edges (probably because the most of the aruco markers at the edges are occluded)
What I am doing to get that corner is to compute the calibration matrix first (using  cv::calibrateCamera as instructed in the charuco detection tutorial), then reproject the points (since the corners are known given the charuco board) and see where it lands. For example, for the point in the image above the reprojection point falls in (141, 74) which is few pixels away from the actual location (157, 82), so I proceeded to use cv::cornerSubPix which seems the next logical step, but to my surprise, cornerSubPix is not getting the corner right, given that the corner is not to hard to find I would say, I am not using the parameters right.
(I tried cv::findChessboardCorners as well, but seems it is not good with cropped edges)

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d4a/tutorial_charuco_detection.html

Can you provide the original image.

@KRG I added the original image,
It is worth mentioning, that the motivation of this question is to be able to identify good corners that the OpenCV charuco detector is not consider because of the occluded Aruco markers.
